# Passing Model on navigation is Null

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project and am trying to pass the serializedForm, which builds the `LRSSearchMaster` Model, to my controller when navigating. So, as stated previously, I have a Model called `LRSSearchMaster`. When I call the page change, it passes all of my parameters successfully, except for the `LRSSearchMaster`. All of the values are null (i.e. Party is null) even though it should not be null. How can I go about passing this Model plus a couple extra parameters to the model when navigating?

**Model**

```
public partial class LRSSearchMaster
{
    public LRS_Party Party { get; set; }
    public LRS_Settings Settings{ get; set; }
    public LRS_IndexedInstrument IndexedInstrument { get; set; }
    public LRS_InstrumentSubType InstrumentSubType { get; set; }

    [UIHint("DateFilter")]
    [DisplayName("Date Filter")]
    public int dateFilterValue { get; set; } = 0;

    public LRS_BookTypes BookTypes { get; set; }

    public DateTime fromDateFile { get; set; }
    public DateTime toDateFile { get; set; }
    public String ReverseSearchName { get; set; }

    public int grp { get; set; }

    public bool selectFile { get; set; } = false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href='@Url.Action("SearchFilter1", "SearchFilter")' onclick='navigate(this.href);'>
    @*<input type="button" value='Submit' />*@
    <input id="btnSearch" type="button" value='Search (F8)' />
</a>
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("SearchByNameLookUp", "SearchByName")",
    data: JSON.stringify({ oSearchByName: oModel }),
    type:"POST",
    success: function (data)
    {
        if (data.succeed != true)
        {
            alert(data.errors);
            bContinue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            oModel = data.oModel;
            url = target + "?SM=" + JSON.stringify(data.oModel) + "&searchType=" + 1;
            window.location.href = url
        }
    },
    error: function (data)
    {
        alert("Error creating/loading Case. Please refresh the page and try again.");
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SearchFilter(LRSSearchMaster model, int searchType = 0)
{
    List<LRSSearchMaster> liSM = GetFilteredResults(model, searchType);
    ViewBag.searchType = searchType;
    return View("~/Areas/LRSSearch/Views/SearchFilter/SearchFilter.cshtml", liSM);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your code where "oModel" variable comes from in your Javascript environment. Presuminging that oModel actually contains what it should, I would suspect that either your AJAX parameter name in Javascript should be **model**, or your controller variable should be **oSearchByName**.

I've only ever used JSON for the parameters when writing API2 however, so if you can't get the JSON working, you might be better passing a Javascript field for each field in the model like:

```
{ model_Var1: 'a', model_Var2: 'b', ... }
```

Comment: Yeah, it's currently named model. I've read that it doesn't pass the Model because a navigation is a get method? They were older posts so I do not know if that still pertains anymore. Or maybe it could potentially be because I have multi level tiers in the model? Meaning the Party class is in the LRSSearchMaster. So it's actually LRSSearchMaster.Party.SearchName.  Could that be why it is null maybe?

Answer (score 0):

So what I eneded up doing was converting my model into a json string and sent it to my controller. Although my parameter was still null, I was able to access the string by doing Request.QueryString[MyParameterName]

```
url = '@Url.Action("SearchFilter", "SearchFilter")?model=' + JSON.stringify(data.oModel) + "&searchType=" + 1; window.location.href = url;
```

Then in my controller I did the below.

```
model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LRSSearchMaster>(Request.QueryString["model"]);
```

And wahlah! I now have everything that was passed.

I would have used a form submit, but the client wanted to be able to send the URL to someone.